# Only replace column

Tags: sql, sqlite

What would be the best way to replace an entire row in a table with values, but only replace a specific value if the one we have is not NULL.

To elaborate, I currently use this query:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO items (name, quantity, last_user) VALUES ('test', '3', 'John');
```

Now what I am trying to do is run the above query, and only replace the last_user if the value specified is not NULL. The rest I would like to replace anyway.

So ideally, if the last user is now NULL, keep the last field. I could of course do a `SELECT` statement to grab the last known value, check if the new one is NULL and if it is insert the last known value instead - but I would like to do this using a single query.

Comment: If what specified value is not NULL?  What is the "last user"?

Answer (score 2):

Use an update statement with `COALESCE`, passing the old and new values. This will allow you to keep the existing value if it's not null, and replace it if it is null.

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET
    name = 'new-name',
    value = COALESCE(value, 'possible-new-value')
WHERE

    id = 1;
```